# MySQL: Help with script needed

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `hotel_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23061 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

So, i have table 'photos.'
Now i want ALTER this table and add column 'type'.

```
ALTER TABLE photos
ADD COLUMN type varchar(50) default 'jpg'
```

But there is one problem:
column 'photo' contains path - '/foo/bar.jpg' or '/foo/bar.png' and i want to update 'type' column according to 'photo' column content. So type must be 'jpg' if photo ends with 'jpg' or type must be 'png' if photo ends with 'png'.

I have no idea how to write such script...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` statement for that:

```
update  photos
set     type = case
                   when photo like '%.jpg' then 'jpg'
                   when photo like '%.png' then 'png'
                   else null
               end
```

Or if the type is always the last 3 characters:

```
update  photos
set     type = right(photo, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but this doesn't really sound like a job for the database engine. I would recommend setting `type` when the record gets added .

Also, the file extension is no guarantee that an image is actually of the specified type. It could be a good idea to check for this - in PHP, for example, you would use [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize).

Comment: You're absolutely right, however in this case it looks like he wants to do it just once to update the data already in his database.